# WordPress automatically creates wp-content folder when I rename it

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to rename the wp-content folder but WordPress automatically creates it again.

I am adding the code below in wp-config.php file:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */

if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )

define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

define ('WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME', 'assets'); 
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR', ABSPATH . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME) ;
define('WP_SITEURL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_CONTENT_URL', WP_SITEURL . WP_CONTENT_FOLDERNAME);
```

Then I rename 'wp-content' to 'assets' but WordPress automatically  creates the wp-content folder again.

Is this normal? Am I doing everything correct?

I also tried this by iThems plugin but is the same.

Comment: and why are you renaming it? It is not recommended to rename it.

Comment: no, it seems it is because of some plugin or theme. some code checks if some file exists or not, then tries to create it. You need to check inside wp-content after each re-creation. is it empty? if it is empty, then it needs some debugging, if not, then created filename inside it would tell you the reason.

Comment: Vural Acar, I think I can improve my WordPress site and to make it more secured. I am follow this post https://www.hongkiat.com/blog/renaming-wordpress-wp-content-folder/

Comment: Thanks Elvin85, 

the wp-content folder appeared when I added new image in media library
Probably you are right that is because of the theme, because now all plugins are deactivated. I am using Betheme.

Also I noticed that the links for all images works both:
../assets/uploads/2016/04/background.jpg
../wp-content/uploads/2016/04/background.jpg

How this is possible when wp-content has only the new uploaded image?